# how to read doc file content using phpword?

Tags: javascript, php, linux, ms-office, codeigniter-3

I want to read doc file content:
PHPWord is installed via Composer. and added dependency into phpword.
for reading the content am using this code its loading blank view.

```
require_once 'autoload.php';
$fileName = "test.docx";
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($fileName);
$PHPWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate($fileName);
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$xmlWriter->save("php://output");
$sections = $phpWord->getSections();
$section = $sections[0];
$arrays = $section->getElements();
```

Comment: You can try `$content = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source, 'MsDoc');`

Comment: @Ravi Chaudhary, i have done changes ,even though am getting same

Comment: I tryed Phpword i'm unable to read the content ,its only generating the file.
so i can able to read the html and odt file format.
is there any converter like doc/docx to html or odt in php?